# how to run random command through datapack?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I want to do random command from a list to run but in datapack and without taking space from a world also for a tick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something similar but more easier
for who that want to do

the generator

https://misode.github.io/loot-table/

what I do after is
(in main function) for running command:

```
/execute if score @s RANDOM matches <any number in range that not used>  run function <namespace>:<function>
```

(in the end of the function)for not repeated commands:

```
/scoreboard players set @s RANDOM 0
```

Comment: Your method may be better for simplicity, but mine is better for having a bigger range of outcome.  My way is for automation, and there is no hard-coding needed.  If this works for you then great.  This just might not work for others.

Answer (score 1):

## 1.15+

My solution uses an nbt array, grabs a random number, takes the value at index that was generated, and runs the command in a command block.

### Preparation in Minecraft

So in preparation, you will need an array in a storage which we’ll call `rcg` with each command as a value.  **Make sure the commands are in strings**.  You can do that with the following command.

```
data modify storage rcg commands set value [<values>]
```

If you ever want to add another command, the process is simple.  All you need to do is append the command.  The process is what follows.

```
data modify storage rcg commands append value “<command>”
```

Now, we need a `Impulse Command Block` set to `Needs Redstone` to run the command.  We’ll put the command block at coordinate `0 0 0`.

### Preparation Outside Minecraft

Now, we need a random number generator.  Cloud Wolf has a random number generator that can use a range.  The rng comes with trig as well although we won’t need trig for this.  The download link is [here](https://api.github.com/repos/cloudwolfyt/math_lite/zipball/master).  Now you need to install the datapack into your world and then you are ready to go.

### Core Commands

Now, we get to the commands.  So in a new function, we need a command to retrieve the length of the command array and store it in the range max scoreboard value.  We’ll call this function `main`.  You can do that with the following command.

```
execute store result score in1 math run data get storage rcg commands
```

Now, we run the function for the rng.

```
function math:rng/range
```

Next, we set a new nbt array to the original one to iterate through the array later.

```
data modify storage rcg itercommands set from storage rcg commands
```

Now, we need a new function to remove the first value from the `itercommands` array, remove 1 from the generated number, then run the function again unless the out value is 0.  We’ll name this function `findatindex`  The following commands does this.

```
data remove storage rcg itercommands[0]
scoreboard players remove out math 1
execute unless score out math matches 0 run function <namespace>:findatindex
```

Now, we run this new function unless out is 0.

```
execute unless score out math matches 0 run function <namespace>:findatindex
```

Next, we take the first value in the `itercommands` array and store it in the command block’s command.

```
data modify block 0 0 0 Command set from storage rcg itercommands[0]
```

Next, we power the command block by using one of multiple methods.  1: We modify the command block to set always active on. 2: We modify the command block to set powered to true. 3: We set a redstone block next to it.  I will go with the 3rd.

```
setblock 0 0 -1 redstone_block
```

Finally, we schedule another function for 1 tick in the future, to remove the redstone block.  We’ll call it `rcg_end`.

```
schedule function <namespace>:rcg_end
```

There you go.  You are finished.  Please let me know if you have any bugs or questions.

Comment: There is a way less complicated at least without /data because I so confused from this I guess you've been working this alot but there is a simpler way?

Comment: What is the source of randomness that the data pack provides?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 the datapack uses lcg to generate numbers.